Are reels forbidden during the Omer because of background music?
I know there are already various opinions on recorded music but I'm interested specifically in posts on social media, where music is used in the background for complimentary rather than festive purposes (same with films actually) and wouldn't be consumed on its own without the video or the talking in the background.
My guess would be that it is preferable to avoid but actually numerous frum pages are posting lots of material be it inspirational hiddushim or whatever else with music in the background so it got me wondering if maybe this is entirely acceptable to begin with.

3 good questions ... background music is not an issue in elevators, shopping centers, etc. And many say permitted when done to quiet oneself (vs. have fun). I assume the same is true here as well - not an issue unless the goal is to create joy through music. Note this might be different in the 3 weeks before 9Av. Looking forward to more questions and some good answers !

The Agudah uses background music for its videos presented on 9 Av itself.
